# Show that $\|uv^T-wz^T\|_F^2\le \|u-w\|_2^2+\|v-z\|_2^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that $\|uv^T-wz^T\|_F^2\le \|u-w\|_2^2+\|v-z\|_2^2$, assuming $u,v,w,z$ are all unit vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach: note that for orthogonal matrices $U,V,$ we have
$$
\|uv^T - wz^T\|_F^2 = \|U(uv^T - wz^T)V\|_F^2 = \|(Uu)(Vv)^T - (Uw)(Vz)^T\|_F^2.
$$
So without loss of generality, we can assume that $u = v = (1,0,\dots,0)^T$, so $uv^T$ is the matrix with a $1$ as its $1,1$ entry and zeros elsewhere. The left-hand side is then given by
$$
\|uv^T - wz^T\|_F^2 = \|wz^T\|_F^2 + [(1 - w_1z_1)^2 - (w_1z_1)^2] \\
= (w^Tz)(z^Tw) + [1 - 2w_1 z_1] = 2 - 2w_1z_1.
$$
The right hand size is given by
$$
\|u - w\|^2 + \|v-z\|^2 = \|w\|^2 + [(1 - w_1)^2 - w_1^2] + \|z\|^2 + [(1 - z_1)^2 - z_1^2]
\\ = 2 - 2w_1 + 2 - 2z_1 = 4 - 2(w_1 + z_1),
$$
and from there the reasoning is similar.

---

Another approach for expanding the exact expression: note that
$$
M = uv^T - wz^T = \pmatrix{u & w} \pmatrix{v & -z}^T,
$$
so that
$$
\operatorname{tr}(MM^T) = 
\operatorname{tr}[\pmatrix{u & w} \pmatrix{v & -z}^T\pmatrix{v & -z}\pmatrix{u & w}^T] 
\\ = 
\operatorname{tr}[\pmatrix{v & -z}^T\pmatrix{v & -z}\pmatrix{u & w}^T\pmatrix{u & w}] 
\\ = 
\operatorname{tr}\left[\pmatrix{1 & -v^Tz\\ -v^Tz & 1}\pmatrix{1 & u^Tw\\u^Tw & 1}\right]
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=u^Tw,b=v^Tz.$

$\|uv^T-wz^T\|_F^2=tr((uv^T-wz^T)^T(uv^T-wz^T))=2-2ab$

And RHS=$4-2(a+b).$

Check that $2-2ab\le4-2(a+b) \iff a+b-ab\le1,$ using that $|a|\le1, |b|\le 1.$

Comment: Are you posting this to share your answer, or are you showing it because you want your answer checked?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I I was looking to some alternative solutions. Thank you for providing them

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=(u-w)v^T$ and $B=w(v-z)^T$. The inequality in question is then equivalent to
$$
\|A+B\|_F^2\le\|A\|_F^2+\|B\|_F^2.
$$
It is true if and only if $\langle A,B\rangle_F\le0$. Indeed, this is the case because
$$
\langle A,B\rangle_F
=\left[w^T(u-w)\right]\left[v^T(v-z)\right]
=(w^Tu-1)(1-v^Tz)\le0.
$$